# Google Chrome Flash Depreciation

Tags: google-chrome, flash, swfobject

How does www.hotstar.com show "allow flash" alert on clicking "Get Adobe Flash Player" button which shows up when flash is not enabled on the site but it is installed on Chrome?? I need to implement this functionality...Please help

Comment: Instead of just asking about somebody else's site. Show a link to your own problem page. Make a temporary one, if you need to. Then ask a question regarding your page (where you have ability to adjust the code). Show a fully testable example of minimum HTML code required to display the SWF. You might be looking to add an `alt` element to your embedding code (maybe, but can't see it to advise properly)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if I understand your question but Google Chrome disables Flash content from running by default on all web pages, for security. [Flash can be enabled though.](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html) The web page likely assumes that since Flash is not active when loaded, you have not installed Flash.

Comment: I agree with you but please go to www.hotstar.com and block flash for this site.. Link /Button "Get dobe Flash Player" will appear .On clicking this link,chrome prompts to allow flash...which then enables flash on this site...What I want on my site is that user is able to allow flash on this alert instead going to chrome settings.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I don't think that the prompt you describe allows Flash on the whole site, just the current instance of the page you are on. In my experience, I have always had to manually whitelist sites that I want Chrome to automatically allow Flash to run on to get consistent Flash usage. Not to mention, Flash will not run on any page if Flash is not up to date.